# Implement Multiple client reads a file and multiple servers writes to a file via Client Server

Tags: client-server, distributed-system, file-writing, file-access, file-read

Below is the question, I was asked in an interview,

Datacenter has 10000 servers.We have a single syslog driver which collates all the logs from all the servers in the datacenter and writes it in a single file called syslog.log
Let's say the datacenter has 1000 Admins.At any point of time any admin can login to syslog server and invoke a command say

getlog --serverid  --severity

And the command should continuously tail the logs matching the conditions provided by the user untill he interupts.
Any number of users can concurrently login to this server and run this command. His request should be honoured, but with one condition, at any given point in time there can be only one file descriptor open for syslog.log file.

Implement getlog such that it satisfies the above condition.

I told my approach as Critical Section problem, we can use mutex/semaphore to lock the file until a user finishes. But he is expecting something like Client-Server Model.

How to serve this functionality using client and server architecture?
What is the best approach to solve this?